# Webflux security login failure handler does not work

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm trying to setup with Spring webflux security custom string messages, if the login/logout was successfull or it's failed. The handlers are working except the "authenticationFailureHandler".

The docs mention something about "logoutSuccessUrl()" but it does not exist, and these handlers are returning with Mono< Void >.

So I have 2 questions:

- How do I return some string as a response,  for example if the authenticaion fails then something like "Invalid username or password", or some json string. I tried to redirect to an action, but i can't do it with void Mono.
- Why the authenticationFailureHandler is not working, and every other handler does? Is that a bug?

-I tried to redirect with Mono.just("redirect:/some-url").then(), but it didn't do anything. For the responses

- I made my handlers bean, tried to change the method sequence, disabling/enabling other handlers. For the authenticationFailureHandler.

You can find my whole code here: 
https://github.com/iron2414/WebFluxAuth

It's a modified version of this article's code:
https://medium.com/@mgray_94552/reactive-authorisation-in-spring-security-943e6534aaeb

The security configuration looks like this:

```
 return http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
                    System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
                    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                    });
                })
                .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
                    System.out.println("AUTHENTICATION ENTRTY POINT");
                    ServerHttpResponse response = swe.getResponse();
                    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                    });
                })
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .authenticationFailureHandler(MyAuthenticationFailureHandler()) 

    .authenticationSuccessHandler(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(MyLogoutHandler())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .build();
```

The loginFailure handler:

```
    @Bean
    public MyAuthenticationFailureHandler MyAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
```

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> onAuthenticationFailure(WebFilterExchange webFilterExchange, AuthenticationException e) {
        //TODO redirect
        System.out.println("AUTHENTICATION FAILURE");
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made a fully functional example project implementing webflux + webflux-security, it contains complete workflow about success + failure handlers, you can see here: https://github.com/eriknyk/webflux-jwt-security-demo

Answer (score 0):

For the response i had to use "RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler" for the authentication success. And i created the exact same class that implements for the failure.

The auth failure handler not working is a known issue. In order to make it work you have to set the loginpage. So i just updated it to the default "/login"

Comment: this issue is still not resolved. but your trick for login page works :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and end up using a custom DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler to deal with it:

```
@Component
public class MyGlobalWebExceptionHandler extends DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return route(all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {
        ErrorRepresentation representation = createErrorRepresentation(request);
        return ServerResponse
                .status(representation.getError().getStatus())
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(representation));
    }

    private ErrorRepresentation createErrorRepresentation(ServerRequest request) {
        boolean includeStackTrace = isIncludeStackTrace(request, MediaType.ALL);
        Map<String, Object> error = getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace);
        Throwable throwable = getError(request);


        if (throwable instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            AuthenticationFailureException failureException = new AuthenticationFailureException(throwable.getMessage());
            return new ErrorRepresentation(failureException, error.get("path").toString());
        }

    }
}
```